# How do I access the value of state within a redux store in javascript?

Tags: javascript, redux, grid.js

I am trying to use Grid.js to create a table of data in a Flask app I am building. Grid.js has a checkbox plugin which uses the Redux architecture so that each selection instance keeps the list of selected rows within a Store.

I am following the example code located here: https://gridjs.io/docs/plugins/selection/selection-events

My code can be seen below:

```
grid.on('ready', () => {
          // find the plugin with the give plugin ID
          const checkboxPlugin = grid.config.plugin.get('selectRow');
          // read the selected rows from the plugin's store
          checkboxPlugin.props.store.on('updated', function (state) {
            console.log('checkbox updated', state);
          });
        });
      </script>

<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('about') }}">
  <button name="activity" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value={{state}}></button> 
</form>
```

When I select a checkbox the console.log displays the information I want to access in the console. However I do not know how to assign it to a variable so that I can then use a button to send it back to my Flask app in python using a POST form.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[This is a screenshot of my table, checkbox and value of 'state' which can be seen in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHJyT.png)